# How to decide an optimum value for n_features parameter in Sklearn FeatureHasher

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-selection

I am using hash encoding on a categorical column with 13 different value counts, and ideally speaking one-hot and dummy will give us 12 and 13 columns respectively after encoding. But when it comes to hash encoding, the default value of `n_features is 2**20`, which eventually creates 1000000+ columns.

How does one choose the value of `n_features`? I see that we need to consider a value to the nearest power of 2. Say if we consider the IRIS dataset we can end up using `2` or maybe even `4` for the `n_features`.

But what about a dataset where we have *13 different values in a column*, what would be the `n_features` then?

**# Feature Hashing Code:**

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction import FeatureHasher

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:/Users/<user_name>/Downloads/datasets/countriesoftheworld.csv')
hash_encoder = FeatureHasher(n_features = ????, alternate_sign=False, input_type='string')
features = hash_encoder.fit_transform(df['Country'])

print(df.shape)
```

> (227, 20)

I have not dropped the "Country" column, just to contrast between the original and encoded columns.

```
df = iris.join(pd.DataFrame(features.toarray()).add_prefix('encoded_'))

print(df.shape)
```

> (227, 1048596)

Comment: Why do you want to encode all columns?

Comment: @Corralien, I am encoding one column which has 13 categories in it. Ex. Col A value counts are [a, b, c, d, e, f, g ,h, I, j, k, l, k]

Comment: I understand but in your current dataset `countriesoftheworld.csv`, why do you want to use OneHotEncoder on `Country` column?

Comment: `Country` column is just an example and the value count of this col would be 250~. But the use-case here is, I have a dataset in which there col with13 categories. If I have to feature hash this particular col, what would optimum n_features be, how do we decide on n_features value?